# How to upload a file using VBA (input file)

Tags: file, vba, excel, input

I have this CSV file that it need to be uploaded in a WebSite , but this website have an input type file.

I know its pretty impossible because i spent like three weeks loking for an answer,i found another way to upload the file **WITHOUT USING THE INPUT TYPE FILE*** so i was wondering if anyone found a solution to my probleme

This is what i have :

This is my firt attempt like any average personne using VBA :

```
  Set UploadCSV = IEDoc.getElementById("namecsv") 
  UploadCSV.Value = "something\toto.csv"
```

This is my input type file:

```
    <input name="filename" class="text align_center" id="nomfichiercsv" type="file" size="24" accept="text/html,text/plain" value=""/>
```

Thank's

---

I tried the SendKeys function no luck

Comment: Try Selenium. E.g. your could solve this with Eclipse + Selenium driver

Comment: And whats that ? (i googled it but ..)

Comment: have a look here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xaWLIBKAQps

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned you can do this in an Eclipse project using the Java Selenium driver. Afterwards part of the code could look like this;

```
driver.findElement(By.id("nomfichiercsv")).sendKeys(UploadCSV);
driver.findElement(By.id("submit")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, you can use the below code after you have identified the element:

```
driver.FindElementById("Id of the element").SendKeys ("path to the input file")
```

If the frame changes when you are trying to upload the file, you will need to switch to the new frame.
If Id is not present for the element, use other Web Element selector methods.