# Handling alert popups using selenium in linux platform

Tags: java, linux, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I have an application to automate using selenium webdriver that has feature to browse and upload a file to the website. In windows, it was easy to use autoIt with selenium. It works fine. But if same code has to work on linux machine, the .au3 script might not work the way its expected to. Is there any alternative for this or I can still use same .au3 script to run on linux platform?

Is there any tool that can help me handle these popups on linux platform? I searched in this forum, but couldn't get any solution for my problem.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: Are you sure you even need autoit for Windows? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032500/how-to-upload-a-file-using-vba-input-file/25061563#25061563

Comment: Thanks for response kokkie. I checked the video, the link you pasted but I didn't get anything on how to handle windows pop up. Can you helpme how to use the code mentioned in that post please?

Comment: Never mind I got the solution. Thanks Kokkie it took some time to understand your code. I used your code and it worked. Find the code snippet I used "driver.findElement(By.id(<id>)).sendKeys(<filepath>)", it works fine.